# Accessing temp tables from inside a WITH clause

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @tempNums TABLE(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    val INT
);

DECLARE @tempNames TABLE(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(10)
);

DECLARE @combined TABLE(
    val INT,
    name VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @tempNums(val) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO @tempNames(name) VALUES ('one'),('two'),('three');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        @tempNums.val AS 'val',
        @tempNames.name AS 'name'
    FROM @tempNums
        INNER JOIN @tempNames
            ON @tempNums.val = @tempNames.id
)
MERGE INTO @combined
    USING cte ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (val,name)
    VALUES(cte.val, cte.name);

SELECT * from @combined;
```

Results in the following error message:

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1.
Must declare the scalar variable "@tempNums".
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1.
Must declare the scalar variable "@tempNames". (Line 25)
```

How can I access temporary tables from within a WITH clause?

RANDOM TEXT TO MAKE THE STUPID "MOSTLY CODE" WARNING GO AWAY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are NOT temp tables, they are table variables and must be treated a little differently. You need to use an alias in your query instead of trying to use the name of the table variable again. You really should get in the habit of using aliases all the time anyway.

```
DECLARE @tempNums TABLE(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    val INT
);

DECLARE @tempNames TABLE(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(10)
);

DECLARE @combined TABLE(
    val INT,
    name VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @tempNums(val) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO @tempNames(name) VALUES ('one'),('two'),('three');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        tNum.val AS 'val',
        tName.name AS 'name'
    FROM @tempNums tNum
        INNER JOIN @tempNames tName
            ON tNum.val = tName.id
)
MERGE INTO @combined
    USING cte ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (val,name)
    VALUES(cte.val, cte.name);

SELECT * from @combined;
```

Comment: If this solved your problem you should mark this as the answer.